# How to export only some public sub-keys with gpg?

Tags: gpg, pgp

My PGP-key follows the long-lived-mainkey-short-time-subkeys pattern. Thus I already have 12 expired subkeys attached to my mainkey. When handing out my key today, there seems to be not much reason to include the expired encryption subkeys - nobody's going to need them anymore.

Is there a way to only export a few of the **public** subkeys along with the (public) mainkey?

I tried to explicitly export the two current subkeys, which should provoke the mainkey to be exported alongside:

```
gpg -a --export <subkey13-id> <subkey14-id> >output.file
```

But this command exported the complete key: mainkey with *all* subkeys.